# overlay page in views

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have a little problem with display data queried from mysql database table
the data obtained is 3d array and I would like to use it in a javascript function

Usually, data in cake php is displayed in a ctp page whose file name(excluding the extension) is the same as the controller function's. 
I would normally call that page if I click on a link in the current page as

```
<a href='../nextpage'>Next page</a>
```

or

```
<input type='button' onclick='../nextpage'>
```

'nextpage' is a ctp page (nextpage.ctp) as well as a controller function name

My problem is like this

database data queried ---sent to---> current page (having a link/button)---click to open ---->nextpage

next page will again display some data queried from the database. I sure can make nextpage as a new ctp page but I would like to make nextpage as an overlay page (a popup that grays out its parent once it shows up). 
Is there any to accomplish this ?

Comment: :( I found no similar questions

Comment: not questions...if you want to use jquery, and it's plugins, you can get a hell lot of those...or if you want the vanilla js or jquery-but-no-plugins way, i can answer that...but plugins are readymade and easy to use...

Answer (score 0):

You could have an HTML link with the following markup:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someJavascriptFunction()">Next page</a>
```

which will trigger a javascript function defined as

```
<script>

function someJavascriptFunction(){

//do something here

}

</script>
```